# How to directly pass a string to a member function

Tags: c++, object, error-handling

I tried to create a class Person with data members: name and age; and member functions: getName and gerName. i was to create a parameter constructor in such a way that `Person P1("Jeff",28)` is a valid input.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Person
{
private:
    char* name;
    int age;
public:
    Person(char arr[],int n);
    ~Person();
    char *getName()const;
    int getAge()const;
};

Person::Person(char arr[],int n)
:name(arr),age(n)
{
}

Person::~Person()
{
}

char * Person::getName()const  //note that name and 
//the return type of this function both are pointers
{
    return name;
}

int Person::getAge()const
{
    return age;
}
```

then i did the application:

```
Person P1("Jeff",29);
    cout<<"name: "<<P1.getName()<<" age: "<<P1.getAge()<<endl;
```

the code was executed but i received an error:
ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

on searching, i found out this error is received on executing faulty codes.

**Is there a proper way to create a parameter constructor that satisfy my requirements?  ( initialise an object as P1("Sam",22))**

i expected the code to run smoothly, but i got an error which i don't know how to fix.
I'm a beginner in coding and an example code or link to any resources will be appreciated.

Comment: Tip: Consider using `std::string` vs. the perpetually problematic C string `char*`.

Comment: Calling this `arr` is pretty dirty as it's actually `name`. Likewise, `n` is `age`.

Comment: Tip: Stop `using namespace std` and instead embrace the `std::` prefix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems are mainly:

1. You do not use `std::string`
2. In your constructor "char arr[]" will decay to `char *arr`
3. The data type of the literal "Jeff" is `const char[5]`
4. You cannot assign a `const char[5]` to a `char *`

Do not use a string literal in the call of the constructor.

First create a string, like `char name[] = "Jeff"` and then give name to the constructor.

Im my very humble opinion this should not even compile. My ISO c++ compliant compiler does not compile it. The resulting program will most likely show undefined behavior.

Use `std::string` in the first place. It is that easy and superior to `char[]` that it definitely should be used